# IE @Html.TextBoxFor onchange event does not work

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I run into an issue with IE 11 and onchange event in input type="text".

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PartNumber, new { @onchange = "OnChangeEvent()" })
```

```
function OnChangeEvent() {
        some logic
}
```

On chrome it work like a charm but on specific version of IE 11 it doesn't work at all. Even the window.onload event doesn't fire in IE. I searched the internet but so far every solution I tried is not working.
Is there some kind of solution for that ? Basically I want to achieve a way when user inputs some string in the text box (rather by scanner not manually) and the there is a Ajax action to controller to retrive data.

Comment: Start using chromium based Edge instead. IE11 is dead. https://death-to-ie11.com/

Comment: I wish I could. Some users in company still use IE and IE is also on handheld scanners...

Comment: Does the jquery change() method work (instread of using the onchange call)?

$("PartNumber").change(function(){
alert("Changed!");
});

Comment: Problem here is also that I onload function is not working on IE and it's hard to check

Comment: how are you calling the onload function?

Comment: I tried different approaches. Calling on the view side in script section <script>
 window.onload = functionName
</script> or document.ready function.In chrome there is no problem. In IE with every approach. But it must be specifc version of the IE 11 because on other PC with different IE 11 version it works

Comment: I tried to test the issue on my side and found that onchange event works fine with the IE 11 browser. See test result [here](https://imgur.com/a/EiYFHbt). It can be a cache related issue. Hard refresh the page by pressing the  `CTRL + F5` key. You said it did not work with the specific version of the IE browser, Does it works on any other machine with the IE 11 browser? Did you see any error message in the console? Does it only happen when you try to assign the string using a scanner? If yes, please provide information about it. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: It is related to specifc version of IE 11. On 11.2906.14393.0 it doesn't work. However I found a option to setting to enable active scripting but I don't think this is a good solution. But on version 11.1726.17134.0 everything works as expected

Comment: I tried to workaround this and add button but the same issue. Even onclick doesn't fire by default. Changing the setting I mention does the trick but by default this site will be lunched from handheld scanner and I don't think there is a way there to change that setting.

Comment: It looks like the Javascript is disabled on that IE. I suggest you go to the `Internet options -> Security tab -> Internet or Intranet zone -> custom level button -> Active Scripting` and enabled it. Then your code will work fine. If that setting is controlled by your organization then you can contact your IT department and discuss with them whether they can enable this option for you. If this option is disabled then your code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an arrow function, use a function. IE11 does not support arrow functions, along with many other things.

You should also look into using a polyfill too.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(function(model){ model.PartNumber, new { @onchange = "OnChangeEvent()" }})
```

Comment: Not really my case